# Receiving this error while trying to load the weights for Mask RCNN

Tags: python, mask-rcnn

```
# Create model object in inference mode.
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir='mask_rcnn_coco.hy', config=config)

# Load weights trained on MS-COCO
model.load_weights('mask_rcnn_coco.h5', by_name=True)
```

This is the code i am using

```
AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "roi_align_classifier" (type PyramidROIAlign).
```

in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mrcnn/model.py", line 390, in call  *
    roi_level = log2_graph(tf.sqrt(h * w) / (224.0 / tf.sqrt(image_area)))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mrcnn/model.py", line 341, in log2_graph  *
    return tf.log(x) / tf.log(2.0)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'log'
```

I have already changed tf.log to tf.math.log but i dont know why it does not update.

Comment: Did you change tf.log to tf.math.log everywhere? As of my understanding your code in line 341 is still tf.log. So maybe you didnt changed it everywhere or after you changed it tensorflow is loaded again and is causing that it doesnt use tf.math.log?